# PHPStorm Update Error

Tags: phpstorm

I just updated my PHPstorm to build # PS-138.940. All of my plugins cannot be loaded. This is the message i get in my event log.

```
 Plugin Error
           Error loading plugins:
           Plugins should not have cyclic dependencies:
           org.coffeescript->com.intellij.plugins.html.instantEditing->...->org.coffeescript
           Plugins were not loaded.
           Correct the above error and restart IDEA.
```

The problem is not with only CoffeeScript plugin as the error is saying but with all my plugins. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

remove the LiveEdit.jar in your WebIde80 directory.. see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23919